# WW1 British Army Records

Tags: england, military-records, world-war-1

Both my uncles were in WW1 and their records were among those burnt in London in WW2.  Is there anywhere else that would hold records of them?
One was in the Essex Regiment and the other in the Royal Fusiliers.  He lost a leg which was replaced by a German one, could he have been a Prisoner of War?

Comment: Barbara, I've closed this as it has significant overlap with the question indicated, other than the piece about Prisoners of War (which I've now addressed there). If the answers to the other question don't address everything, you can edit this one to be specific about the information you're still missing and it can then be re-opened.

Comment: Many thanks for your rapid reply.  I'll certainly look for the suggestions you recommend.  B Morris

Comment: @BarbaraMorris - if you are asking a generic 'how do I find out about' question, then I agree it's a duplicate. If however you are asking about specific individuals, then you should include more detail. I presume they are deceased and you should include that (this site does not help locate living individuals). Include their names and what you do know of them in a new question and that would be appropriate as not a duplicate. If you do find what you are looking for from the suggestions in the other Q, you might still ask your question and then answer it yourself.